# Can't send mail via sendmail

Tags: email, sendmail, mail-command

I'm trying send mail via sendmail, but mail is not received. Here is the command:

```
/bin/cat /scripts/zabbix/test.txt | mail -v -s "Blocked IPs" example@example.com
```

Here is the output

```
example@example.com... Connecting to [127.0.0.1] via relay...
220 nshost1.example.am ESMTP Sendmail 8.15.2/8.15.2; Fri, 3 Feb 2017 13:05:32 +0400 (AMT)
>>> EHLO nshost1.example.am
250-nshost1.example.am Hello localhost [127.0.0.1], pleased to meet you
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE
250-DSN
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-DELIVERBY
250 HELP
>>> STARTTLS
220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
>>> EHLO nshost1.example.am
250-nshost1.example.am Hello localhost [127.0.0.1], pleased to meet you
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE
250-DSN
250-ETRN
250-DELIVERBY
250 HELP
>>> MAIL From:<david@nshost1.example.am> SIZE=76
250 2.1.0 <david@nshost1.example.am>... Sender ok
>>> RCPT To:<example@example.com>
>>> DATA
250 2.1.5 <example@example.com>... Recipient ok
354 Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself
>>> .
250 2.0.0 v1395W8n061857 Message accepted for delivery
example@example.com... Sent (v1395W8n061857 Message accepted for delivery)
Closing connection to [127.0.0.1]
>>> QUIT
221 2.0.0 nshost1.example.am closing connection
```

Here is the maillog output

```
Feb  3 13:05:27 nshost1 sendmail[61739]: v1395R0Q061739: from=david, size=76, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201702030905.v1395R0Q061739@nshost1.example.am>, relay=root@localhost
Feb  3 13:05:32 nshost1 sm-mta[61857]: ruleset=check_relay, arg1=localhost, arg2=127.0.0.1, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1], discard
Feb  3 13:05:32 nshost1 sm-mta[61857]: STARTTLS=server, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1], version=TLSv1.2, verify=NO, cipher=DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits=256/256
Feb  3 13:05:32 nshost1 sendmail[61739]: STARTTLS=client, relay=[127.0.0.1], version=TLSv1.2, verify=FAIL, cipher=DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits=256/256
Feb  3 13:05:32 nshost1 sm-mta[61857]: v1395W8n061857: from=<david@nshost1.example.am>, size=408, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201702030905.v1395R0Q061739@nshost1.example.am>, proto=ESMTPS, daemon=IPv4, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Feb  3 13:05:32 nshost1 sm-mta[61857]: v1395W8n061857: discarded
Feb  3 13:05:32 nshost1 sendmail[61739]: v1395R0Q061739: to=example@example.com, ctladdr=david (1007/1007), delay=00:00:05, xdelay=00:00:05, mailer=relay, pri=30076, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (v1395W8n061857 Message accepted for delivery)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have any `DISCARD` entries in your access (map) sendmail configuration file?

Comment: No,here is access file content                                                                    ## Examples (commented out for safety)
To:example.am                      OK
From: nshost1.example.am           OK
localhost.localdomain           RELAY
localhost                       RELAY

Comment: @David please put your updates in the question, not here in the comments. For starters it means you can format the text properly, and so be going on with, comments are often ignored by people reading the question as they are expected to be requests for clarification, etc.

Comment: The line `Connecting to [127.0.0.1] via relay` looks extremely suspect. Does this host (think it's) called `example.com` as per your target email address?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you  Andrzej A. Filip.My problem is solved after I run

```
make restart
```